# Passing large sequences as function parameters

Tags: f#, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

This is a simple question really (but I couldn't seem to find the answer in the MSDN documents).

If I pass large sequences and objects as function parameters in F#, are they always copied by value unless I supply the byref keyword?  The thing is, I have no intention of modifying the arguments, but at the same time, I don't want the large objects to be copied each time I call the function.

Comment: I strongly feel that anyone who says "arrays are passed by reference" is abusing terminology in a way that is likely to confuse new learners, but acknowledge that my feelings may be in the minority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default sequences/lists/arrays are passed by reference

for example

```
let mutate (arr:int[]) =
    arr.[0] <- 1

let t = Array.zerocreate 1
mutate t
printfn "%i" (t.[0]) //prints 1
```

Comment: If that's by default, you mean there is some way to do it differently?

Comment: @svick - you could probably do something nasty if you really wanted to with structs and use that to fake arrays

Comment: So is it correct to say that a very similar concept as in C#, in which there are value types and reference types, also applies here?  Is anything that is allocated on the heap always a reference type?

Comment: @Shredderroy Just as in C#, F# has reference and value types. And just as in C#, both value and reference types can be allocated on the heap depending on context.

Answer (score 10):

I disagree with the terminology people are using here.

I would phrase it as: everything in .NET is pass-by-value by default, the exceptions are e.g. `ref` and `out` parameters in C# and `byref` parameters in F#.  However, sequences and arrays and most other types (aparts from structs and primitives) are object references, which means when you pass them as arguments (by value), you are passing only a reference to the entity, and the caller and callee share the same actual entity on the heap.  So the references are being passed by value, but the references themselves are just small things, whereas the object entities they point to (that contain all the data) are large things that are shared on the heap.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments, F# uses essentially the same mechanism as C#. This means that only *value types* (primitive values such as `int`, `float` and structs) are copied on a stack and all other types are passed by reference - this includes all collections (sequences `seq<'T>`, arrays `'T[]` as well as immutable functional lists `list<'T>`).

When you're working with immutable types (functional `list<'T>` and `seq<'T>` without side-effects), there is no difference between passing a reference and copying the object aside from performance - the runtime always passes them as reference, but you don't need to worry about this unless you're optimizing some program (if you could change the passing mechanism, it would not change the behaviour).

For (mutable) arrays, you can easily see that the behaviour is pass-by-reference by looking at the exampe from John Palmer's answer.

As a sidenote, the `byref` keyword (or type) is used if you want to create a reference to a stack-allocated mutable variable. This means, you can use it to pass reference to a variable of a value type:

```
let bar (a:byref<int>) =    // takes reference to a (stack-allocated) 'int' variable
  a <- 42                   // mutate the variable

let mutable foo = 10        // declare a mutable variable
bar &foo                    // pass reference to the `bar` function
```

If you were passing collections using `byref`, you'd be actually passing a reference to a stack-allocated reference that actually points to the heap-allocated data structure. However, `byref` is used very rarely in F# - you'll mainly need it for interoperability when calling C/C++ or COM library.

Comment: thanks so much for your response.  And thanks a lot for all the articles and books, among my main sources for learning F#.  But since John Palmer was the first to answer the basic question, I feel morally obligated to accept his response.

Comment: @Shredderroy I'm glad some of my work was useful! John definitely gave you the right answer (+1 for that!) - I just thought I could add some more details.

Comment: "and all other types are passed by reference" No, all other types are *reference types*, whose values (references) are also passed by value.

Answer (score 0):

As Values are immutable so same Sequence which you have passed will be modified or used in.. 
objects will not be copied each time..

Although If you modify Sequence then a new Sequence will be created with new Values